# Python script for forwarding streaming data

Tags: python, port, forwarding

I'm trying to take incoming data from one port and stream it to a port on another computer. Here is what I have so far:

```
import socket
port = 8787
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print ("waiting on port:", port)
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print (data)
```

`

So I can stream the data in from the port using the script above no problem. What I need to do is now take that data stream and forward it to a port on another computer. I came across this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from socket import *
bufsize = 1024 # Modify to suit your needs
targetHost = "192.1.1.2"
listenPort = 8788

def forward(data, port):
print "Forwarding: '%s' from port %s" % (data, port)
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("localhost", port)) # Bind to the port data came in on
sock.sendto(data, (targetHost, listenPort))

def listen(host, port):
listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
listenSocket.bind((host, port))
while True:
    data, addr = listenSocket.recvfrom(bufsize)
    forward(data, addr[1]) # data and port

listen("localhost", listenPort)
```

But I'm not sure where to put the outgoing port. The IP for the home server that I'm pulling data on has an IP of say 192.1.1.1 and is streaming data in from port 8787. The remote server has an IP of say 192.1.1.2 and it's listening on port 8788. I'm not sure where I need to put port 8787, which is where the home server is pulling in the data from. Any suggestions would be most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that last code you quoted runs on your 192.1.1.1, you need to call `listen("localhost", 8787)` in the last line instead of `listen("localhost", listenPort)`, and you should be fine. `listenPort` refers to the port where the server that the data is being forwarded to (192.1.1.2) is listening, while `listen` expects the port where the current machine (192.1.1.1) listens for input. `listen` then calls `forward` (telling it to use the same port for the outgoing connection).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Now I get this error:
`error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

Can I use this? `s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `sock.bind(("localhost", port))` in the forward function, try removing it. You might also want to check out the [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) in the python docs.

Comment: Thanks. That worked now it says data is not defined. I'm heading over to your link to see what I'm missing in defining my data.

Comment: Had trouble defining the data. So this is what I went with. `import socket
port = 8787
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print ("waiting on port:", port)
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(data, ('192.168.1.100',8788))`

Thank you so much for pointing out the issue with the sock.bind and giving me the link. Once I narrowed it down to needing to define the data I was able to rework it. Thanks!